# I have 0 for id in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

In a mysql database I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE `actualities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When I try to create a new entry in this table, the ID is set 0 like this :

```
mysql> insert into actualities (title) VALUES ('title');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.13 sec)

mysql> select * from actualities order by created_at desc limit 1;
+----+-------+------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title | body | project_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  0 | title | NULL |       NULL | 2012-12-15 20:14:20 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+-------+------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I don't understand why. Do you have a solution?

**SOLUTION**

```
ALTER TABLE actualities MODIFY id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: It might be because you didn't have it auto_increment. Try another query and see what the ID is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you want is this :

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Without this, you need to give a specific value when inserting new data in your table or else it will take the default value (here `0`)

More info on the documentation of MySQL for [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Is it possible to change the column without remove and recreate the table/column?

Answer (score 4):

The default value for a `NOT NULL` int field is 0. `id` is a primary key, so it is `NOT NULL` one way or another.

Depending on what your expected behavior was, you can:

1. Turn on `AUTO_INCREMENT`
2. Include an `id` value in your `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 3):

> For numeric types, the default is 0, with the exception that for integer or floating-point types declared with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, the default is the next value in the sequence.

[MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)